# Need help going from single pole to double pole thermostat

Tags: thermostat

[image]I am trying to replace single pole thermostats with double pole in two adjacent rooms. In each outlet there are three black, three red and three grounding wires. When I removed the single pole thermostats one was connected to black wires and the other to red. The load had one line connected to it and the line had two. All the demos I have found refer to only two black and two red wires...

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes?

Comment: That's not weird, it just means either a) this stat controls 2 heaters in which case the double are on the LOAD, or b) this line also went on to supply other 'stats in which case the 2 are on the LiNE.